# Why this code works? (bizarre syntax in javascript)

Tags: javascript

I found this line of code works:

```js
 for(let in [0,1,2]) {console.log('wtfjs');}
```

but not these:

```js
 for(var in [0,1,2]) {console.log('js');}
for(const in [0,1,2]) {console.log('js');}
```

(Try those on Chrome, Firefox even Edge!)

I'm totally puzzled with it.

*Found Another one*

```
for(let of [0,1,2]) {console.log(let);}
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: The answer must be hidden somewhere in the [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements), yet I cannot find it

Comment: @UlysseBN [Section 11.6.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words). "`let` and `static` are treated as reserved keywords through static semantic restrictions rather than the lexical grammar." In other words, `let` and `static` are contextual keywords. They are either a keyword or a variable name, depending on context.

Comment: I understood why `let in []` works. But why `let of []` does not...?
Knowing this is useless in real-world code, I'm really curious.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that let implies the variable name 'let' where var and const do not imply a name. You need a variable or const name in the ones that don't work. Like this:

```
 for(var x in [0,1,2]) {console.log('js');}
 for(const y in [0,1,2]) {console.log('js');}
```

Comment: Why the negative votes?

Comment: You missed the point.  The OP is asking why the first example works without a variable name, when the second two instances don't

Comment: "let implies a null variable name" — It doesn't. Let is treated as the variable name. You can test it by logging the value of `let`. Any explanation as to why that is the case (i.e. a good answer) would probably need to reference the specification.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. edited my answer.

Comment: I've found another strange code.